# Bringing parts of TFS to Subversion using git-tf, git-svn

Tags: git, svn, tfs, git-tf

I would like to only commit a subset of data from the TFS repository to the Subversion repository.

So far,

- I have cloned the TFS repository:

  git tf clone --deep http://tfs.server.com:8080/tfs/TeamA "$/Project/Development

In Development, there are four cloned folders (DEV, DEV-A, DEV-B, PROD-Branch) where only two should make it to Subversion (DEV and PROD-Branch).

- I have initialized the SVN and fetched it:

  git svn init https://subversion.com/svn/TeamA/
  git svn fetch
- I have rebased it:

  git rebase --onto git-svn hash_number_here master

I was initially thinking of passing parameters to the dcommit command, however having looked at the documentation, there doesn't seem to be a parameter for this (think of svn ci and passing paths to commit)

git branch shows only one branch, ***master**.

Could I have simply removed the unwanted folders from Development?

I also found this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26453458/503246

Familiar with SVN and Hg, not so much with Git.

**Edit #1**

How about committing everything to a temp SVN repo, and filtering out the folders that I don't want, dump and import into final destination?

**Edit #2**

I used svndumpsanitizer to filter the dump file to import and the resulting import didn't show any errors. However, the code doesn't compile properly now, missing files which were probably nuked during this process.

Comment: I would be more interested in addressing the why!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing, once it was rebased onto a local **temporary** repository:

- Initialized and fetched into a temporary local repository
- Export dump of temporary repository
- Filter out the needed folders using [svndumpsanitizer](https://github.com/dsuni/svndumpsanitizer)
- Import into destination repository